# How to customize button loading with getx flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I would like to customize a button that showed loading action while fetching data from API using GetX which I can pass any controllers.

Note: Each controller has field **isLoading**

Example:

1. UserController
2. DepartmentController
3. SubjectController

```
class BtnAction<T> extends GetView<ConnectivityController> {
  final String text;
  final GestureTapCallback press;
  final Color color;
  final Color textColor;
  final T isLoading;

  const BtnAction(
      {Key? key,
      required this.text,
      required this.press,
      required this.color,
      required this.isLoading,
      required this.textColor})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      if (controller.connectionStatus.value.name == 'none') {
        return TextButton.icon(
            onPressed: null,
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey),
            label: Text(text, style: TextStyle(color: textColor)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.wifi_off_sharp, color: textColor));
      } else {
        if (isLoading as (T).isLoading) {
          return TextButton(
            onPressed: press,
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
              backgroundColor: color,
              primary: textColor,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            ),
            child: Text(text),
          );
        } else {
          return TextButton(
            onPressed: press,
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
              backgroundColor: color,
              primary: textColor,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            ),
            child: Text(text),
          );
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

//on click
SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 15),
              child: BtnAction<UserController>(
                text: "Filter",
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.black,
                isLoading: controller,
                press: () async {
                  controller.fetchUser(UserRequest());
             
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Please kindly give me some advice on how can I achieve this.

Thank you!!

Comment: so you need to pass controller and loading value and need to show enabled button only when while loading is false. isn't it?

Comment: Hello @Mahi
I have updated the question a bit.

Yes, I want to show the loading spinner button as an example above when user clicks on 
BtnAction, when fetching done, then my controller will change the status of isLoaing to false so mean spinner will replace by "Filter" button

I want to use this class BtnAction as general by passing the difference controller.

is it possible to do that?
Please you give me advice 

Thank you!

Comment: I will just pass the controller into the constructor of the button and use loading value of controller to check the loading status, and depends on the value (inside obx) changes the button or loading spinner. loading value should be .obs